# How to extract specific info from JSON data on PostgreSQL

Tags: json, metabase

I would like to kindly ask for your help regarding the JSON Data on MySQL.

```
[
  {"type" : "PET", "rate_period" : "MONTHLY", "amount" : 100.00, "included" : false},
  {"type" : "PARKING", "rate_period" : "MONTHLY", "amount" : 150.00, "included" : false}
]
```

Here is the form of the data and I would like to extract the info for each category (type, rate_period, amount). Keep in mind that I am working on Metabase and does not recognize the Commands (SPLIT_PART, JSON_EXTRACT).

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

What I actually tried:

```
SELECT p.deal_info::json->>'{}')::json->>'type'
FROM deals
```

[Code on SQL where I just get the Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6YhU.png)

Comment: You tag a question for MySQL, but use the syntax specific for PostgreSQL. Check your DBMS carefully.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the comment and the edit. Actually, the data exist on metabase in the Form that I show you above.  You can edit them with PostgreSQL or MySQL.

Comment: Let's assume that you'd use pure SQL. Show desired result for shown source query.

Comment: I added a photo with the Data and the code. I just use a select to bring them.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE test
SELECT 1 id, CAST('
[
  {"type" : "PET", "rate_period" : "MONTHLY", "amount" : 100.00, "included" : false},
  {"type" : "PARKING", "rate_period" : "MONTHLY", "amount" : 150.00, "included" : true}
] 
' AS JSON) data;
SELECT id, CAST(data AS CHAR) FROM test;
```

```
SELECT id, jsontable.*
FROM test
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(test.data,
                      '$[*]' COLUMNS ( type VARCHAR(255) PATH '$.type', 
                                       rate_period VARCHAR(255) PATH '$.rate_period', 
                                       amount DECIMAL(10,2) PATH '$.amount', 
                                       included BOOLEAN PATH '$.included'
                                       )) jsontable
```

| id | type | rate_period | amount | included |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PET | MONTHLY | 100.00 | 0 |
| 1 | PARKING | MONTHLY | 150.00 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zl3wQHK4)

Comment: Thanks for your help! Metabase does not recognize the COLUMNS command and I have to think of a workaround. However, your way seems very viable.

Comment: @stefanos_1992 in this case the mysql tag cannot apply to your question as this answer follows mysql syntax.

Comment: @stefanos_1992 *Metabase does not recognize the COLUMNS command* According the documentation ".. Metabase sends the query to your database exactly as it is written." And, as the fiddle proves, the query is successfully processed by MySQL. You use incorrect method for the query execution obviously.